# TFS Build/Deploy task : Default multiline value for a field

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild

For a TFS build/Deploy task I am trying to set a default value for a field. The json for the field is as below:

```
{
  "name": "RegexPattern",
  "type": "multiLine",
  "label": "Regex Pattern",
  "required": true,
  "defaultValue": "__(\\w+[\\.\\w+]*)__\\n__(\\w+)__"
}
```

With this value I am not getting the default value in the field in 2 lines but in 1 line with \n literally being present.

When I add the task in a build or release definition I would like to set the value **(\w+[\.\w+]*)** in 1 line and **(\w+)** in the 2nd line.

Any thoughts on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it by just not escaping the backslash on the newline. Also try including a linefeed, so `\r\n`.

This works for me with PowerShell; your mileage may vary if you're using a different language.

`"defaultValue": "__(\\w+[\\.\\w+]*)__\r\n__(\\w+)__"`